# Can I swap speakers from current car to new car?

Tags: audio, speakers

Just bought a new car(Civic em1 1999) but it has horrible quality sound. Pioneer system though so I imagine speakers just need changing.

Old car has good sound.  Instead of buying new speakers, if I remove the speakers from old car will it fit into the new car?  Or do they come in sizes and fits so it's not possible? How can I know?

Thanks

Comment: measure them...

Comment: The Crutchfield site has (what used to be anyway) an excellent sizing tool.  https://www.crutchfield.com/S-WaJcEkghSel/car/carselector.aspx  YMMV